# What's the best way to register components into the component builder from other directories?

Tags: jss, nextjs

I'm working on a monorepo solution which would have a set of Shared components one level above the site folder.
I'm looking at updating `scripts\generate-component-builder\plugins\components.ts` per the [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/jss/latest/jss-xmc/scaffold-and-auto-register-your-own-components-in-a-next-js-app.html) and if I specify `../shared/component` it gets registered to the site `src\temp\componentBuilder.ts`, however when building the site, the file can't be found as it is on a different directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of messing about to be done for external "shared" project folders owing to the fact that the file paths are relative to the current project root initially and then when it generates the `src\temp\componentBuilder.ts` file the paths need to be relative to the location of the that file in the temp folder. As a result this is one way to do it (be interested to hear if anyone has a more elegant way..) We're just replacing the relative paths in the output array returned to be the value we need inserted into the `src\temp\componentBuilder.ts` file.

[image: updates to the OOTB generate-component-builder components plugin file]